# Call a function that was overridden in parent class

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, ecmascript-6

Having two classes:

```
class Parent {
   foo () {
      console.log("foo parent");
   }
}

class Child extend Parent {
   foo () {
      console.log("foo child");
      // Is there a better way than this?
      Parent.prototype.foo.call(this);
   }
}
```

Instead of `Parent.prototype.foo.call(this)`–is there a better way?

To call the parent constructor I use `super`. I am thinking if there is a similar way to call the original function (from parent) which was overridden in the child class.

Comment: Check my answer, it's absolutely possible to use `super` in methods. You can try a working sample here: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iiy8sa7t/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` can be also used with regular methods:

```
class A {
  foo() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  foo() {
    super.foo();
  }
}

// outputs "hello world" to the console log
new B().foo();
```

Comment: @IonicăBizău `super`, `super`!! ;)

Comment: Have a `super.newYear()`! :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău `super.sameForYou()` hahaha